# Spring security 3.0.3 configuration error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, configuration, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring-security to handle authentication and authorization of my web application. I can't get the configuration right. Tomcat trows an error when I deploy the war file.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
```

I got the following configuration.

WEB-INF/spring/web-application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.html*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <form-login login-page='/jsp/loginform.jsp'/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="bob" password="bobspassword" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/web-application-context.xml
      </param-value>
  </context-param>


  <filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exception message clearly says that class `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException` is missing, therefore you need to add `org.springframework.transaction-*.jar` to the classpath (i.e. to `/WEB-INF/lib`).